# HTML Fixed header not hiding glyphicons

Tags: html, css

I have a fixed header and everything works fine in that it hides the texts as the user scrolls on the page. However, I have noticed that the icons in the glyphicons show through the background of the fixed header. My CSS is

```
#taskHeader{
  background: lightgrey;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1.0;
}
```

This fixed header is defined in the HTML as follows:

```
<div class= "row" id="taskHeader">
  <div class="col-md-6"><%= @task.name %></div>
  <div class="col-md-6"><%= @task.description%></div>
</div>
```

Then I have a heading that contains a glphyicon:

```
 <h2> Subtasks
   <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-adjust"></span>
 </h2>
```

Anyone have an idea as to why the glyphicons are visible through the fixed header?

Comment: could you include your html also

Comment: Added relevant html code.

Comment: Can you recreate your problem in jsfiddle so we can take a look at the whole thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be helpful to provide the CSS code that relates to the glyphicons.

However from the information you've provided, I think it's possible that the glyhicons have a higher z-index than #taskHeader - in this case they would appear on top of the header as you scroll past them, as if they "show through" the header as you say. Try setting #taskHeader with a z-index higher than any other element on the page. For example, try:

```
#taskHeader{
  background: lightgrey;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  opacity: 1.0;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

Just make sure the z-index value you use is the highest on the page (I think 10 would work in most cases).

If that fixes the issue, then you have a conflicting z-index for the glyphicons (or their container element).

(Also you probably don't need to define an opacity value of 1.0 on an element as that is the default)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using Material Designs glyphicons (.mdi), the culprit was "display:inline-block". Changing display to "inline" solved the issue.